# how to call webservice periodically in background iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have web service and i want to call this service periodically from my iPhone application  to cash the data  every 1 min when the application is running .

I use **NSTimer** to call the function that call this service but i what to be sour that the first call did finish parsing the data from the first call before proceed a new call . 
so how can i do that ?

```
{
 NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60.0];
 NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                                      interval: 10
                                        target: self
                                      selector:@selector(calltimer:)
                                      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
 [runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
 [t release];
}

-(void)calltimer :(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"yessss");

    if(!myQueue)
    {
        myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("supperApp.user1025523.com", NULL);
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
            [self getData]; 
            });
    }    
}

-(void)getData
{
    webserviceCaller* wsCaller = [[webserviceCaller alloc]initWithTarget:self     selector:@selector(parsINVData:)];
    [wsCaller getINventoryData:self.username];
    [wsCaller release];
}

-(void) parsINVData:(InvData*) ret
{
    //save return data in global variable      
}
```

I use **NSMutableURLRequest** to initiate the request parameter and **NSURLConnection** to start the connection so why the call to the web service didn't fire .

Comment: Much cleaner would be to not setup your timer to repeat. And then when you receive or fail (in NSURLConnection delegate methods) you can reschedule the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a serial queue to ensure that one task waits for the next.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    parsing_queue = dispatch_queue_create("superApp.user1025523.com", NULL);

    // etc.

- (void)timerAction: (NSTimer *)tim
{
    // Enqueue the work. Each new block won't run until the 
    // previous one has completed.
    dispatch_async(parsing_queue, ^{
        // Do the work
    });
}
```

This also automatically in the background.

Comment: OK i do what you say but the function that call the URL did no call the server i update the post with my code

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class level member variable like the following:

in .h file

```
{
    BOOL finishedParsing;
}

- (void) nsTimerFunctionCall
{
    if(!finishedParsing)
    {
        //Either return, or recall this same function after some time
        return;
    }

   [self parseCode];
}

- (void) parseCode
{
    finishedParsing = NO;

    //do long processing function
    //....

    finishedParsing = YES;
}
```

This way you can ensure that the parse code will not be called while another call to the function is processed